# Matrices: knowing that $M^3=N^3$ and that $MN^2=NM^2$, how to prove $M^2+N^2$ is non-invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The exercise:
Let $M$ and $N$ be two distinct $n\times n$ matrices such that  $M^3=N^3$ and that $MN^2=NM^2$. Prove that $M^2+N^2$ is a non-invertible matrix.

I guess I need to show that the determinant is zero, or create a proof by contradiction, but I can't find a good demonstration.

Answer (score 8):

By contradiction, if it exists $A$ such that $(M^2+N^2)A=I$.

Then

$$M=MI=M(M^2+N^2)A=(M^3+MN^2)A=(N^3+NM^2)A=N(N^2+M^2)A=N$$

In contradiction with the hypothesis $M \neq N$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $(M-N)(M^2+N^2)=M^3-NM^2+MN^2-N^3$.

Can you finish?

Comment: On this way, I think $(M-N)(M^2+N^2)=0$ implies that if $(M^2+N^2)$ were invertible, $(M-N)$ would be $0$ and then $M=N$, a contradiction. Is that right?

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho Good!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the identity $MN^2 = NM^2$:

$$
\begin{align*}
 &\Leftrightarrow  
MN^2 +M^3= NM^2 +N^3 \\ &\Leftrightarrow
M(N^2 +M^2)= N(M^2 +N^2) \\
\end{align*}
$$
Now, if $N^2+M^2$ were invertible, we'd arrive at $M=N$.